# Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

While I'm turning off internet connection on the phone I have an exception

```
Cannot evaluate the expression: : Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation
Cause: Can not generate outer receiver value for class <closure-StartViewModel$fetchCurrentWeek$1>
```

When internet is on, everething works fine!

Exception appears in function fetchCurrentWeek, on line

```
val currentWeek = WeekSource(ApiFactory.rozkladKpiApi).getCurrentWeek()
```

StartViewModel.kt

```
package andy.schedulekpi.ui.fragments.start

import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import andy.schedulekpi.network.api.ApiFactory
import andy.schedulekpi.network.sources.GroupSource
import andy.schedulekpi.network.sources.SourcesFactory
import andy.schedulekpi.network.sources.WeekSource
import andy.schedulekpi.ui.fragments.base.BaseViewModel
import andy.schedulekpi.utils.SHARED_PREFERENCES_GROUP
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class StartViewModel : BaseViewModel() {
    // TODO: Implement the ViewModel

    private val source = SourcesFactory.weekSource

    val mCurrentWeek : MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()

    fun fetchCurrentWeek() {
        scope.launch {
            val currentWeek = WeekSource(ApiFactory.rozkladKpiApi).getCurrentWeek()
            mCurrentWeek.postValue(currentWeek)
        }
    }

    fun getGroupFromSharedPreferences(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences) : String {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(SHARED_PREFERENCES_GROUP, "null")!!
    }

    fun isGroupCachedInSharedPreferences(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences) : Boolean {
        return sharedPreferences.contains(SHARED_PREFERENCES_GROUP)
    }


}
```

Image: 
image of debugger: https://ibb.co/fNSLZZM

Comment: It's a bug, follow this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=%22Backend%20Internal%20error:%20Exception%20during%20code%20generation%22